# vscode snippet in html attribute, how?

Tags: visual-studio-code

is it possible to trigger snippets when the cursor is inside html attributes? I've setup some html snippets which work fine in the html file, but not inside the attributes. Is that possible?

Comment: what's in this snippet's `"scope"` property? The reason why I ask is because- for example, the `style` attribute's value is given CSS language mode (see also [embedded languages docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages)). So if you create a snippet with `"html"` scope instead of `"html,css"`, the snippet won't be available in a `style` attribute's value context.

Answer (score 1):

Change the setting

`Editor: Quick Suggestions` to enable `strings`

Mouse over the `strings` value and a pencil edit option will appear on the right side, click it so you can choose `on`.

Since the html attributes are enclosed in strings, you need to make this change.

Comment: Wow! You saved my day, sir! I have a snippet to add an open/close PHP tag and I wanted to use it inside the HTML attributes. Thank you!